# How do I test if requestStream is closed and disposed

Tags: vb.net

How do I test if requestStream is closed and disposed if the exception occurs

```
Try
    Using requestStream As Stream = rqst.GetRequestStream()

        requestStream.Write(fle, 0, fle.Length)

        Throw New ApplicationException("Exception Occured")

    End Using


Catch ex As Exception

    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString())

Finally
    'test if the requeststream is closed and disposed?
    MessageBox.Show("")

End Try
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's what `Using` does. Even if there's an exception, `using` causes the compiler to bake in a `finally` clause that will call `Dispose`.

No need to do it again.

Comment: thanks is it possible to test? im told implement idispose but not sure how?

Comment: There's no `Disposed` property on `IDisposable`, so probably not, although you could try some operations on `requestStream` after `End Using` and ensure that they throw `ObjectDisposedException`.

Comment: Oops. Yes, the Using statement has it's own scope.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to solve this using some mocking and fake implementations, but Stream base class is not friendly to that.
Finally I have solved it there in unit test using exactly same principle as spender suggests (C# used):

```
[TestMethod]
[ExpectedException(typeof(ObjectDisposedException))]
public void When_EmailResource_gets_disposed_Should_dispose_ContentStream()
{
    var stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();

    var resource = new EmailResource
    {
        ContentStream = stream,
    };

    resource.Dispose();

    stream.ReadByte();
}
```

stream.ReadByte(); causes the exception.

Maybe there it exists a bit cleaner way with help of SystemWrapper, see https://systemwrapper.codeplex.com/

HTH